# Messed up string value received on the server side - multilingual

Tags: java, php, encoding

I have written client side rest services on php and the server side is on Java.

I am sending  a value `அகம்.com.my` using the client side webservice and trying to  perform some operation on the server side. The received value is `à® à®à®®à¯.com.my`

what can I do to receive the string in the same format. I tried to encode the value into base64 and decoded on the server side but still the received value is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it so posting the solution.

on php end:

```
 urlencode($domainName);
```

Decoded and used UTF-8 on the server side (java):

```
  domainName= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(domainName, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a 'content-type' header in your requests.
You need to inform the server what kind of data you're sending so it will know how to process it correctly.

For example, if you're sending plain text in UTF8, you can add the following line in your client code :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

Comment: No, just send the value. Interpreting the content from the request should be done by the underlying Http library or your REST provider.